# Send gzip request in VBA

Tags: xml, vba, gzip, httprequest

I have some trouble. I need to send some xml as http request and I need to gzip it on VBA in Excel.
xml is simple string.
I am using WinHTTPRequest.

Web-service should accept this xml, but gzip compressed.
How can I do this?

P.S. sorry for my English. Hello from Russia! :)

Comment: You mean you need to send a gzipped xml file? I assume this is via POST request?

Comment: Providing some code, HTML and ideally an URL would have made this [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

With your HTTP request, you need to set the request header of 'Accept-Encoding' to specify that gzip is available:

```
WebSrvc.SetRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding","gzip"
```

You can find more information about the "Accept-Encoding" in the [W3 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) Under section 14.3

Comment: I've already use this header, besides "X-Requested-With" header. I think I need some algorithm to decode my string XML with gzip, deflate. I realized this thing with C# and it works fine with web-service.